# .htaccess/mod_rewrite: West <--- Main Site ---> East

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would really appreciate anyone's help with a mod_rewrite question. I don't know regex and am not familiar with .htaccess directives, so I can't think of how to solve the problem I am having.

Below is a description of what I am trying to accomplish...

3 websites:

```
http://www.example.com/ or http://example.com/
http://east.example.com/
http://west.example.com/
```

Have pages on main site that need to be redirected to other sites:

```
http://www.example.com/location1
http://www.example.com/location2
http://www.example.com/location3
http://www.example.com/location4
http://www.example.com/location5
http://www.example.com/location6
```

Need to redirect some pages to one website based on location, e.g http://east.example.com/:

```
http://www.example.com/location1 redirect to http://east.example.com/location1
http://www.example.com/location2 redirect to http://east.example.com/location2
http://www.example.com/location3 redirect to http://east.example.com/location3
(also without www) e.g.
http://example.com/location1 redirect to http://east.example.com/location1
```

Need to redirect some pages to another website based on location, e.g http://west.example.com/:

```
http://www.example.com/location4 redirect to http://west.example.com/location4
http://www.example.com/location5 redirect to http://west.example.com/location5
http://www.example.com/location6 redirect to http://west.example.com/location6
(also without www) e.g.
http://example.com/location4 redirect to http://west.example.com/location4
```

Want a rewrite rule that works like:

```
If domain name is www.example.com or domain name is example.com
And domain name is not east.example.com
And domain name is not west.example.com
And "somelocation" (in the east) is in the URL
Then Rewrite(Redirect) URL to http://east.example.com/.../somelocation/.../somepage
```

> NOTE: the three websites actually share the same codebase, so the URLs all point to the same location/.htaccess file. So, I tried using a basic redirect, and ended up with an error that said... can't open page because of too many redirects.

If anyone knows the answer and can help with this, I would really appreciate the help!

EDIT: Example of expected results

Original URL:
"http://www.example.com/locations/eastend-web-page"

Rewritten URL:
"http://east.example.com/locations/eastend-web-page"

Comment: Can you provide a couple of concrete examples or urls that have somelocation/somepage in the east that you want redirected and what they should redirect to

Comment: Hi... looking for Original URL:
http://www.example.com/locations/eastend-web-page

Rewritten URL:
http://east.example.com/locations/eastend-web-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to fill a rewritemap file (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)) to make a correspondance with the URLs that are part of your "east" domain. You may declare it like this:

```
RewriteMap mapmaintoeast \
  dbm:/web/htdocs/yoursite/rewriterules/mapmaintoeast.map
```

Regarding your sample, your map file may be filled with things like:

```
eastlocation1        mainlocation1
eastlocation2        mainlocation2
eastlocation3        mainlocation3
...
```

I've called them 'east' and 'main' to distinguish clearly. These examples are supposed to be URLs.

Do the same for west:

```
RewriteMap mapmaintowest \
  dbm:/web/htdocs/yoursite/rewriterules/mapmaintowest.map
```

In that file:

```
westlocation1        mainlocation4
westlocation2        mainlocation5
westlocation3        mainlocation6
...
```

Then here you go for the hard part:

```
# This cond put any non-empty string into "%1" (= parenthesis + first cond):
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
# The following rule doesn't touch the URL, but 
# will try to search into the map file and
# create fill an environment variable called MAINTOEAST with the
# string found and if not found, assign MAINTOEAST to "notfound"
RewriteRule . - [QSA,E=MAINTOEAST:${mapmaintoeast:%1|notfound}]

# if MAINTOEAST not empty and different from "notfound":
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAINTOEAST} !^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAINTOEAST} !(notfound)
# ok found => redirect to east:
RewriteRule (.*) http://east.example.com$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

# Now do the same with west (no comments needed (see previous)):
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule . - [QSA,E=MAINTOWEST:${mapmaintowest:%1|notfound}]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAINTOWEST} !^$
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAINTOWEST} !(notfound)
RewriteRule (.*) http://west.example.com$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This should work.
I hope I've given you enough clues to finish the job ;)
If you don't have enough clues...

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your answer looks like a great solution. I'm running into problems though, and can't seem to get it working, so I had to come up with a workaround instead. I'm having the website figure out the redirection instead of the web server. It's a performance hit, but it's a small price to pay to get it working. Thanks again for your help. One of these days I will learn regex/mod_rewrite and put your suggestion to use.

Comment: My pleasure! If you think it's useful and this question is solved, either check one of the answers here or write your own answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
# If domain name is www.example.com or domain name is example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
# And "somelocation" (in the east) is in the URL, 
# Then Rewrite(Redirect) URL to http://east.example.com/.../somelocation/.../somepage
RewriteRule ^(.*somelocation.*)$ http://east.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

You'd need to do the same thing for west. Note that if the domain name is www.example.com or example.com, it *cannot* be east.example.com or west.example.com

Comment: Hi Jon... Thanks so much for answering. I tried what you suggested, and doesn't seem to work for me. Hi Jon… So, if I used...

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*eastend-web-page.*)$ http://east.example.com/$1 [R,L]

Should this work?

Original URL:
http://www.example.com/locations/eastend-web-page

Rewritten URL:
http://east.example.com/locations/eastend-web-page

Comment: Hi Jon... not sure why it's not working. Let me know if there's anything else I could try to debug. Wondering what ^(.*somelocation.*)$ pattern matches in my example, and what would be added by $1

Comment: `^(.*somelocation.*)$` will match **some_path/somelocation/some_file.html** and the **$1** means replace with everything that was matched inside the parentheses, or in this case, **some_path/somelocation/some_file.html**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Your answer looks like it should have worked, however I'm running into problems, and had to come up with a workaround instead. I'm having the web site figure out the redirection instead of the web server. It's a performance hit, but a small price to pay to get it working. Thanks again for your help.